# Unable to start Hybris Tomcat Server due to Solr Server

Tags: tomcat, solr, sap-commerce-cloud

I am not able to start the Hybris server due to the starting issue with SOLR server.

Kindly help me in this regard so that I can start the Hybris tomcat server.

### error log:

```
INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] [DefaultSolrServerService] Starting Solr server for instance: [name: default, port: 8983]
Waiting up to 30 seconds to see Solr running on port 8983 [/]
Started Solr server on port 8983 (pid=8405). Happy searching!
.
.
.
INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] [AbstractSolrServerController] Solr server not yet started for instance: [name: default, port: 8983] [retry: 7, interval: 5000ms]

INFO: (Enh120375):  AspectJ attempting reweave of 'org/tanukisoftware/wrapper/WrapperSimpleApp'
INFO: (Enh120375):  AspectJ attempting reweave of 'org/apache/catalina/startup/Catalina'
INFO: (Enh120375):  AspectJ attempting reweave of 'org/tanukisoftware/wrapper/WrapperManager'
INFO: (Enh120375):  AspectJ attempting reweave of 'org/apache/catalina/util/LifecycleBase'
INFO: (Enh120375):  AspectJ attempting reweave of 'org/apache/catalina/core/StandardContext'
.
.
INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] [AbstractSolrServerController] Solr server not yet started for instance: [name: default, port: 8983] [retry: 10, interval: 5000ms]

ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] [AbstractSolrServerController] Solr server is still not running after calling start command for instance: [name: default, port: 8983]
ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] [DefaultSolrServerService] de.hybris.platform.solrserver.SolrServerException: Solr server is still not running after calling start command for instance: [name: default, port: 8983]

WARN  [localhost-startStop-1] [CloseAwareApplicationContext] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultSolrServerService' defined in class path resource [global-solrserver-spring.xml]: InvINFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/08/16 14:14:10.627 | ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] [AbstractSolrServerController] Solr server is still not running after calling start command for instance: [name: default, port: 8983]

INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/08/16 14:14:10.627 | ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] [DefaultSolrServerService] de.hybris.platform.solrserver.SolrServerException: Solr server is still not running after calling start command for instance: [name: default, port: 8983]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/08/16 14:14:10.627 | WARN  [localhost-startStop-1] [CloseAwareApplicationContext] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/08/16 14:14:10.627 | org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultSolrServerService' defined in class path resource [global-solrserver-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is de.hybris.platform.solrserver.SolrServerException: Solr server is still not running after calling start command for instance: [name: default, port: 8983]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/08/16 14:14:10.627 |         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/08/16 14:14:10.627 |         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/08/16 14:14:10.627 |         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/08/16 14:14:10.627 |         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/08/16 14:14:10.627 |         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/08/16 14:14:10.627 |         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/08/16 14:14:10.627 |         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/08/16 14:14:10.627 |         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/08/16 14:14:10.627 |         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/08/16 14:14:10.627 |         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/08/16 14:14:10.627 |         at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory.refreshContext(HybrisContextFactory.java:98)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/08/16 14:14:10.627 |         at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory$GlobalContextFactory.build(HybrisContextFactory.java:176)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/08/16 14:14:10.627 |         at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getGlobalInstanceCached(HybrisContextHolder.java:134)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/08/16 14:14:10.627 |         at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getGlobalInstance(HybrisContextHolder.java:113)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/08/16 14:14:10.627 |         at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.getSingletonGlobalApplicationContext(Registry.java:1059)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/08/16 14:14:10.627 |         at de.hybris.platform.cache.impl.RegionCacheAdapter.getController(RegionCacheAdapter.java:76)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/08/16 14:14:10.627 |         at de.hybris.platform.cache.impl.RegionCacheAdapter.getOrAddUnit(RegionCacheAdapter.java:206)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/08/16 14:14:10.627 |         atocation of init method failed; nested exception is de.hybris.platform.solrserver.SolrServerException: Solr server is still not running after calling start command for instance: [name: default, port: 8983]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
.
.
.
        at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.setCurrentTenant(Registry.java:544)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.activateMasterTenant(Registry.java:607)
        at de.hybris.platf de.hybris.platform.cache.AbstractCacheUnit.get(AbstractCacheUnit.java:180)

INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/08/16 14:14:10.628 | WARN  [localhost-startStop-1] [CloseAwareApplicationContext] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/08/16 14:14:10.628 | org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultSolrServerService' defined in class path resource [global-solrserver-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is de.hybris.platform.solrserver.SolrServerException: Solr server is still not running after calling start command for instance: [name: default, port: 8983]
INFO   | jvm 1    |orm.core.Registry.startup(Registry.java:422)
        at de.hybris.platform.spring.HybrisContextLoaderListener.startRegistry(HybrisContextLoaderListener.java:237)
        at de.hybris.platform.spring.HybrisContextLoaderListener.doInitWebApplicationContext(HybrisContextLoaderListener.java:135)
        at de.hybris.platform.spring.HybrisContextLoaderListener.initWebApplicationContext(HybrisContextLoaderListener.java:125)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
        at de.hybris.platform.spring.HybrisContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(HybrisContextLoaderListener.java:80)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.null(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.null(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.null(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: de.hybris.platform.solrserver.SolrServerException: Solr server is still not running after calling start command for instance: [name: default, port: 8983]
        at de.hybris.platform.solrserver.impl.AbstractSolrServerController.retryGetStatusUntilConditionIsTrue(AbstractSolrServerController.java:378)
        at de.hybris.platform.solrserver.impl.AbstractSolrServerController.ensureToStartSolr(AbstractSolrServerController.java:122)
        at de.hybris.platform.solrserver.impl.AbstractSolrServerController.start(AbstractSolrServerController.java:99)
        at de.hybris.platform.solrserver.impl.DefaultSolrServerService.startServer(DefaultSolrServerService.java:107)
        at de.hybris.platform.solrserver.impl.DefaultSolrServerService.startServers(DefaultSolrServerService.java:132)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1702)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1641)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
        ... 53 more

.
.
.
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    t.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1702)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1641)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
        ... 53 more

ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] [DeploymentMigrationUtil] Error while migrating deployments of extension core
org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Context hybris Global Context Factory  couldn't  be created correctly due to, Error creating bean with name 'defaultSolrServerService' defined in class path resource [global-solrserver-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is de.hybris.platform.solrserver.SolrServerException: Solr server is still not running after calling start command for instance: [name: default, port: 8983]
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory.build(HybrisContextFactory.java:317)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory$GlobalContextFactory.buildSelf(HybrisContextFactory.java:189)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory$GlobalContextFactory.build(HybrisContextFactory.java:175)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getGlobalInstanceCached(HybrisContextHolder.java:134)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getGlobalInstance(HybrisContextHolder.java:113)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.getSingletonGlobalApplicationContext(Registry.java:1059)
        at de.hybris.platform.cache.impl.RegionCacheAdapter.getController(RegionCacheAdapter.java:76)
        at de.hybris.platform.cache.impl.RegionCacheAdapter.removeUnit(RegionCacheAdapter.java:259)
        at de.hybris.platform.cache.AbstractCacheUnit.get(AbstractCacheUnit.java:199)
        at de.hybris.platform.persistence.type.ComposedType_HJMPWrapper$FindByCodeExact1FinderResult.getFinderResult(ComposedType_HJMPWrapper.java:1811)
        at de.hybris.platform.persistence.type.ComposedType_HJMPWrapper.ejbFindByCodeExact(ComposedType_HJMPWrapper.java:1870)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at de.hybris.platform.util.Utilities.callMethod(Utilities.java:1069)
        at de.hybris.platform.util.Utilities.callMethod(Utilities.java:1059)
        at de.hybris.platform.persistence.framework.HomeInvocationHandler.invoke(HomeInvocationHandler.java:93)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17.findByCodeExact(Unknown Source)
        at de.hybris.platform.persistence.type.TypeManagerEJB.findByCodeExact(TypeManagerEJB.java:271)
        at de.hybris.platform.persistence.type.TypeManagerEJB.getComposedType(TypeManagerEJB.java:459)
        at de.hybris.platform.util.migration.DeploymentMigrationUtil.migrateSelectedDeployments(DeploymentMigrationUtil.java:458)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.migrateCoreTypes(AbstractTenant.java:910)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.Abst| 2016/08/16 14:14:11.231 |      at de.hybris.platform.persistence.type.ComposedType_HJMPWrapper$FindByCodeExact1FinderResult.getFinderResult(ComposedType_HJMPWrapper.java:1811)
.
.
.
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Context hybris Global Context Factory  couldn't  be created correctly due to, Error creating bean with name 'defaultSolrServerService' defined in class path resource [global-solrserver-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is de.hybris.platform.solrserver.SolrServerException: Solr server is still not running after calling start cINFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/08/16 14:14:11.732 | INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] [HybrisContextFactory] Initializing <<global>> Spring ApplicationContext took: (34.50 μs)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/08/16 14:14:11.732 | de.hybris.platform.core.UninstantiableCoreApplicationContextException: Error creating Spring application context.

INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/08/16 14:14:11.733 | Caused by: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Context hybris Global Context Factory  couldn't  be created correctly due to, Error creating bean with name 'defaultSolrServerService' defined in class path resource [global-solrserver-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is de.hybris.platform.solrserver.SolrServerException: Solr server is still not running after calling start command for instance: [name: default, port: 8983]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/08/16 14:14:11.733 | Error creating Spring application context. Shutting down hybris platform since the system cannot be used without working Spring context...
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/08/16 14:14:11.733 | shutting down hybris registry..
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/08/16 14:14:11.733 | INFO  [Thread-2] [HybrisContextFactory] Initializing <<global>> Spring ApplicationContext took: (44.32 μs)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/08/16 14:14:11.733 | ERROR [Thread-2] [JMXBeanLoader] Can't unregister jmxbeans on shutdown of the tenant <<master>>
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/08/16 14:14:11.733 | org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Context hybris Global Context Factory  couldn't  be created correctly due to, Error creating bean with name 'defaultSolrServerService' defined in class path resource [global-solrserver-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is de.hybris.platform.solrserver.SolrServerException: Solr server is still not running after calling start command for instance: [name: default, port: 8983]
.
.
.
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/08/16 14:14:11.733 |         at de.hybommand for instance: [name: default, port: 8983]
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory.build(HybrisContextFactory.java:317)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory$GlobalContextFactory.buildSelf(HybrisContextFactory.java:189)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory$GlobalContextFactory.build(HybrisContextFactory.java:175)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getGlobalInstanceCached(HybrisContextHolder.java:134)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getGlobalInstance(HybrisContextHolder.java:113)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getAppCtxFactory(HybrisContextHolder.java:164)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getApplicationInstance(HybrisContextHolder.java:90)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.createCoreApplicationContext(AbstractTenant.java:686)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doStartupSafe(AbstractTenant.java:724)
        ... 20 more
Error creating Spring application context. Shutting down hybris platform since the system cannot be used without working Spring context...
shutting down hybris registry..
INFO  [Thread-2] [HybrisContextFactory] Initializing <<global>> Spring ApplicationContext took: (44.32 μs)
ERROR [Thread-2] [JMXBeanLoader] Can't unregister jmxbeans on shutdown of the tenant <<master>>
org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Context hybris Global Context Factory  couldn't  be created correctly due to, Error creating bean with name 'defaultSolrServerService' defined in class path resource [global-solrserver-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is de.hybris.platform.solrserver.SolrServerException: Solr server is still not running after calling start command for instance: [name: default, port: 8983]
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory.build(HybrisContextFactory.java:317)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory$GlobalContextFactory.buildSelf(HybrisContextFactory.java:189)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory$GlobalContextFactory.build(HybrisContextFactory.java:175)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getGlobalInstanceCached(HybrisContextHolder.java:134)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getGlobalInstance(HybrisContextHolder.java:113)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.getSingletonGlobalApplicationContext(Registry.java:1059)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.JMXBeanLoader.getMBeanRegistry(JMXBeanLoader.java:155)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.JMXBeanLoader.beforeTenantShutDown(JMXBeanLoader.java:116)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.notifyTenantListenersBeforeShutdown(AbstractTenant.java:1236)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doShutdown(AbstractTenant.java:987)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doShutDown(AbstractTenant.java:948)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.destroy(Registry.java:309)
        at de.hybris.platform.util.RedeployUtilities.shutdown(RedeployUtilities.java:74)
        at de.hybris.platform.util.RedeployUtilities$1.run(RedeployUtilities.java:38)
INFO  [Thread-2] [HybrisContextFactory] Initializing <<global>> Spring ApplicationContext took: (61.35 μs)
ERROR [Thread-2] [RegionCacheAdapter] Unable to clear cache. Failed on region null. Last key null null
org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Context hybris Global Context Factory  couldn't  be created correctly due to, Error creating bean with name 'defaultSolrServerService' defined in class path resource [global-solrserver-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is de.hybris.platform.solrserver.SolrServerException: Solr server is still not running after calling start command for instance: [name: default, port: 8983]
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory.build(HybrisContextFactory.java:317)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory$GlobalContextFactory.buildSelf(HybrisContextFactory.java:189)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory$GlobalContextFactory.build(HybrisContextFactory.java:175)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getGlobalInstanceCached(ris.platform.util.RedeployUtilities.shutdown(RedeployUtilities.java:74)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/08/16 14:14:11.733 |         at de.hybris.platform.util.RedeployUtilities$1.run(RedeployUtilities.java:38)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/08/16 14:14:12.035 | INFO  [Thread-2] [HybrisContextFactory] Initializing <<global>> Spring ApplicationContext took: (61.35 μs)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/08/16 14:14:12.035 | ERROR [Thread-2] [RegionCacheAdapter] Unable to clear cache. Failed on region null. Last key null null
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/08/16 14:14:12.035 | org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Context hybris Global Context Factory  couldn't  be created correctly due to, Error creating bean with name 'defaultSolrServerService' defined in class path resource [global-solrserver-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is de.hybris.platform.solrserver.SolrServerException: Solr server is still not running after calling start command for instance: [name: default, port: 8983]
.
.
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    |HybrisContextHolder.java:134)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getGlobalInstance(HybrisContextHolder.java:113)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.getSingletonGlobalApplicationContext(Registry.java:1059)
        at de.hybris.platform.cache.impl.RegionCacheAdapter.getController(RegionCacheAdapter.java:76)
        at de.hybris.platform.cache.impl.RegionCacheAdapter.clear(RegionCacheAdapter.java:288)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.shutdownCache(AbstractTenant.java:1061)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doShutdown(AbstractTenant.java:1003)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doShutDown(AbstractTenant.java:948)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.destroy(Registry.java:309)
        at de.hybris.platform.util.RedeployUtilities.shutdown(RedeployUtilities.java:74)
        at de.hybris.platform.util.RedeployUtilities$1.run(RedeployUtilities.java:38)
org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Context hybris Global Context Factory  couldn't  be created correctly due to, Error creating bean with name 'defaultSolrServerService' defined in class path resource [global-solrserver-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is de.hybris.platform.solrserver.SolrServerException: Solr server is still not running after calling start command for instance: [name: default, port: 8983]
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory.build(HybrisContextFactory.java:317)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory$GlobalContextFactory.buildSelf(HybrisContextFactory.java:189)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory$GlobalContextFactory.build(HybrisContextFactory.java:175)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getGlobalInstanceCached(HybrisContextHolder.java:134)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getGlobalInstance(HybrisContextHolder.java:113)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.getSingletonGlobalApplicationContext(Registry.java:1059)
        at de.hybris.platform.cache.impl.RegionCacheAdapter.getController(RegionCacheAdapter.java:76)
        at de.hybris.platform.cache.impl.RegionCacheAdapter.clear(RegionCacheAdapter.java:288)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.shutdownCache(AbstractTenant.java:1061)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doShutdown(AbstractTenant.java:1003)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doShutDown(AbstractTenant.java:948)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.destroy(Registry.java:309)
        at de.hybris.platform.util.RedeployUtilities.shutdown(RedeployUtilities.java:74)
        at de.hybris.platform.util.RedeployUtilities$1.run(RedeployUtilities.java:38)
INFO  [Thread-2] [HybrisContextFactory] Initializing <<global>> Spring ApplicationContext took: (21.21 μs)
ERROR [Thread-2] [RegionCacheAdapter] Unable to clear cache. Failed on region null. Last key null null
org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Context hybris Global Context Factory  couldn't  be created correctly due to, Error creating bean with name 'defaultSolrServerService' defined in class path resource [global-solrserver-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is de.hybris.platform.solrserver.SolrServerException: Solr server is still not running after calling start command for instance: [name: default, port: 8983]
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory.build(HybrisContextFactory.java:317)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory$GlobalContextFactory.buildSelf(HybrisContextFactory.java:189)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory$GlobalContextFactory.build(HybrisContextFactory.java:175)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getGlobalInstanceCached(HybrisContextHolder.java:134)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getGlobalInstance(HybrisContextHolder.java:113)
        at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.getSingletonGlobalApplicationContext(Registry.java:1059)
        at de.hybris.platform.cache.impl.RegionCacheAdapter.getController(RegionCacheAdapter.java:76)
        at de.hybris.platform.cache.impl.RegionCacheAdapter.clear(RegionCacheAdapter.java:288)
        at de.hybris.platform.cache.impl.RegionCacheAdapter.destroy(Region 2016/08/16 14:14:12.036 |    at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getGlobalInstanceCached(HybrisContextHolder.java:134)
.
.
.
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/08/16 14:14:12.537 |
STATUS | wrapper  | main    | 2016/08/16 14:14:14.169 | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Comment: This because your Solr instance wasn't stopped properly, which should stop when you stop `Hybris server` using `ctr +c`.  You can try restarting Hybris server again which might solve your issue or explicitly you can run `ant stopSolrServer` to stop Solr server.

Comment: [find all possible troubleshooting steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49631633/2478134), might help someone!

Answer (score 5):

try adding this to your local.properties file. This should prevent it from starting with your TomCat server.

```
solrserver.instances.default.autostart=false
```

Or another solution it to comment solrfacetsearch in the  localextensions.xml.

Comment: Setting autostart to false solved it for me too! Thanks!

Comment: This makes the storefronts unsearchable and no products are being displayed. Incorrect solution.

Comment: None of my products are being displayed in BackOffice and I assume it's because of this

Comment: Just to make it clear, this solution will work when you have a remote solr server working and in your configuration you specify this remote. If you use it in your local and you don't have a solr server, it will, for sure, not work since you wont have any active solr server, therefore, no products will be displayed.

Comment: @Banns - Truly said!! one can refer [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49631633/2478134) to troubleshoot this issue.

Answer (score 4):

Post hybris v5.5, the solr comes as a standalone server. When we hard stop hybris server by ctrl+c from the command prompt, the hybris server sends a signal to the solr server to stop. Now sometimes, due to this hard stop, the signal is not sent by the hybris server to the solr server, which in turn results in a a hung state. Now, when we restart the hybris server the (already) started solr server is not able to instantiate/register the (bean) services which are required by the hybris server to communicate with the solr and hence the hybris server does not gets back the signal that the (solr) services have been initialized in the solr context.

You can check in the processlist of the server on the port (default 8983) and you will find the solr server running (in actually a non-responsive mode)

To avoid this, please do *ant clean all* and try again. You would be able to successfully restart the server

Hope this helps!

Comment: This has been happening on my Win10, Win8 and Win7Pro boxes at home. Exact same setup seems fine on my work Win7Pro laptop and all my CentOS VMs. 
I tried the above, after which even restarting didnt help. I did run currports on all and didnt find 8983 at all. All I am doing is the basic recipe n2c_acc_plus from H65. All OSs are 64-bit. Any other ideas ?

Comment: @killjoy - refer [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49631633/2478134)

Answer (score 2):

While I also attempted to add `solrserver.instances.default.autostart=false` to the `hybris\config\local.properties` file, it worked to start the hybris server, but it resulted in the search functionality not working and products not displaying in the BackOffice and StoreFront.

A solution that worked was to run the `ant stopSolrServer` command in the terminal at `hybris\bin\platform` directory prior to starting the hybris server. Search functionality continues to work and products display correctly.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to go in my detail answer then just add the below in your local.properties file and you go...

```
solrserver.failOnError=false
solrserver.instances.default.autostart=false
```

---

### Troubleshoot steps to solve your issue

OOTB (post hybris v5.5) default solr configuration ensures that a standalone Solr server is configured, started and stopped together with the platform.

Sometimes, with `ctr + c` the solr instance not stopped properly might lead to such errors.

---

**1. Stop and start Hybris server again** - This
solve the issue most of the time as hybris stopped solr
instance properly this time.

**2. Stop the Solr server manually** - You can run the below `ant` command or find it's process and kill it.

`ant stopSolrServer`

**3. Skip the Solr server error** - If you really don't care about Solr for the current task you can simply add below the property. Which let you Hybris server start
even there will be any error with solr server startup.

`solrserver.failOnError=false`

**4. Setup standalone Solr server** - which can be started/stopped independently from Hybris server. Refer [this to setup standalone Solr server](https://www.helphybris.com/2018/04/install-standalone-solr-in-hybris.html)

```
solrserver.instances.default.autostart=false
```

**5. try to change the port and restart**

**6. Check the Solr log** - Still, you are not able to get the root cause, check `${HYBRIS_BIN}/ext-commerce/solrserver/resources/solr/server/logs` and
look for any more details.

---

### Find the [detail post here](https://www.helphybris.com/2018/04/error-bean-defaultSolrServerService-solr-start-command-hybris.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have also experienced this problem earlier and solved by killing the unresponsive solr process running on 8983. As Vikrant also stated, you can check for the specific process and just terminate it. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there were two opened command lines for different hybris copies. After closed one of them, the server started succesfully. It killed the solr process...
Hope this helps somebody

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes while building i experience also the same problem, and the solution for me is the following:

- Kill all java processes.
- go to {HYBRIS-DIR}\hybris\config\solr\instances\default.
- Check if the default config has no other configuration files inside. If that is the case, delete also the folder, the ant-task responsible of the solr instance only check that the folder exists, not the content. If the there is no folder with default configuration, it will copy it again.
- restart hybris.

Answer (score 0):

In my case with Hybris 6.7 embedded solr , I checked the solr logs (@"hybris\log\solr\instances\default\solr.log") and fixed the issue on solr. Then started Hybris Server successfully.
So the right way to troubleshoot is to see first why SOLR startup is failing by checking it logs.

Answer (score -4):

Well as it clearly says error while creating bean with name default so or server service..so it a straight says bean error ..need to fix if there.without anything.like adding properties.

Comment: This is not a complete answer and is more appropriate as a comment.

Comment: hybris/solr/spring sometimes tend to give misleading error messages due to a glitch in the chain of events